# Reading from file list of chars or list of ints

Tags: haskell

I have a question. There is any solution for reading from file list of tuples ? Depends on content ? 
I know that if i need to read integers i do something like that:

```
toTuple :: [String] -> [(Int,Int)]
toTuple = map (\y -> read y ::(Int,Int))
```

But in file i can have tuples this kind (int,int) or (char, int). Is any way to do this nice ?

I was trying to do this at first in finding sign " ' " . If it was, then reading chars, but it doesn't work for some reason.

[Edit]

To function to tuple, i give strings with tuples, before that i splits lines by space sign.

INPUT EXAMPLE:

```
Case 1 : ["(1,2)", "(1,3)" ,"(3,4)" ,"(1,4)"]
Case 2 : ["('a',2)", "('b',3)", "('g',8)", "('h',2)", "('r',4)"]
```

Comment: Can you show so example input. I'd also recommended taking a look at parsec or attoparsec it's a bit of an effort for the first time,  but definitely worth it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try both and choose the successful:

```
import Text.Read
import Control.Applicative

choose :: Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe (Either a b)
choose x y = fmap Left x <|> fmap Right y

readListMaybe :: Read a => [String] -> Maybe [a]
readListMaybe = mapM readMaybe

toTuple :: [String] -> Maybe (Either [(Int, Int)] [(Char, Int)])
toTuple ss = readListMaybe ss `choose` readListMaybe ss

main = do
    -- Just (Left [(1,2),(1,3),(3,4),(1,4)])
    print $ toTuple ["(1,2)", "(1,3)" ,"(3,4)" ,"(1,4)"]
    -- Just (Right [('a',2),('b',3),('g',8),('h',2),('r',4)])
    print $ toTuple ["('a',2)", "('b',3)", "('g',8)", "('h',2)", "('r',4)"]
```

---

Here is a far more efficient (and unsafe) version:

```
readListWithMaybe :: Read a => String -> [String] -> Maybe [a]
readListWithMaybe s ss = fmap (: map read ss) (readMaybe s)

toTuple :: [String] -> Either [(Int, Int)] [(Char, Int)]
toTuple  []    = Left []
toTuple (s:ss) = fromJust $ readListWithMaybe s ss `choose` readListWithMaybe s ss
```

In the first definition of `toTuple`

```
toTuple :: [String] -> Maybe (Either [(Int, Int)] [(Char, Int)])
toTuple ss = readListMaybe ss `choose` readListMaybe ss
```

`readListMaybe` is too strict:

```
readListMaybe :: Read a => [String] -> Maybe [a]
readListMaybe = mapM readMaybe
```

`mapM` is defined in terms of `sequence` which is defined in terms of `(>>=)` which is strict for the `Maybe` monad. And also the reference to `ss` is keeped for too long. The second version doesn't have these problems.

Comment: Is a problem with file ReadP, it doesn't work. I cannot use modules which may have problem with some versions. : /

Comment: The type of `choose` can be generalized to `Alternative f => f a -> f b -> f (Either a b)`. This is exactly `eitherP` from `Data.Attoparsec.Combinator`.

Comment: The unsafe version could, I believe, be written safely in a stream framework like "`ListT` done right", `pipes`, `conduit`, `machines`, etc.

Comment: @dfeuer, how would you do that? You need to either lazily produce tuples until an error is encountered or to strictly check the whole input before computing anything. In the first case a lof of unnecessary work can be done (assuming the program should respond "no way" and die on wrong input), so it's probably best to first check input ([preventing memoization](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/index.html#memo-off) if needed) and then "unsafely" consume it.

Comment: The solution I intended can actually be accomplished lazily as well: `data FList e a = Nil | Cons a (FList e a) | Fail e`.

Comment: @dfeuer, yes, but then you also need to consume this `FList` as soon as values are produced, which means that you need to compute something, which can be expensive, which is inappropriate if you want to throw an error and shutdown on wrong input. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Computing things isn't always as expensive as storing things. Much depends on the error handling requirements...

Answer (score 2):

As I said it may be a good idea to consider using a parsing library, if the task at hand gets a bit more complicated.

First of all you have the benefit of getting error messages and if you decide to switch to a self declared data Type it is still easily applicable (with slight modifications of course).
Also switching from `ByteString` to `Text` (which are both preferable to working with `String` anyways) is just a matter of (un)commenting 4 lines

Here is some example if you have not had the pleasure to work with it.

I'll explain it some time later today - for I have to leave now.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as X
-- import Data.Attoparsec.Text
-- import Data.Text as X

main :: IO ()
main = do print <$> toTuples $ X.unlines ["(1,2)","(1,3)","(3,4)","(1,4)"]
          print <$> toTuples $ X.unlines ["('a',2)","('h',2)","('r',4)"]
          print <$> toTuples $ X.unlines ["('a',2)","(1,3)","(1,4)"] --works
          print <$> toTuples $ "('a',2)"   -- yields Right [Right ('a',2)]!!
          print <$> toTuples $ "(\"a\",2)" -- yields Right []!!

toTuples = parseOnly (myparser `sepBy` skipSpace :: Parser [Either (Int,Int) (Char,Int)])
  where myparser :: Parser (Either (Int,Int) (Char,Int))
        myparser = eitherP (tupleP decimal decimal)
                           (tupleP charP decimal)
        charP = do char '\''
                   c <- notChar '\''
                   char '\''
                   return c

tupleP :: Parser a -> Parser b -> Parser (a, b)
tupleP a b = do char '('
                a' <- a
                skipSpace
                char ','
                skipSpace
                b' <- b
                char ')'
                return (a',b')
```

### Edit: Explanation

`Parser` is a monad, so it comes with `do`-notation which enables us to write the `tupleP` function in this very convenient form. Same goes for `charP` - we describe what to parse in the primitives given by the `attoparsec` library

and it reads something like

- first expect a quote
- then something that is not allowed to be a quote
- and another quote
- return the not quote thingy

if you can write down the parser informally you're most likely halfway through writing the haskell code, the only thing left to do is find the primitives in the library or write some auxilary function like `tupleP`.

A nice thing is that `Parsers` (being monads) compose nicely so we get our desired parser `eitherP (tupleP ..) (tupleP ..)`.

The only magic that happens in the `print <$>..` lines is that `Either` is a functor and every function using `<$>` or `fmap` uses the `Right` side of the `Either`s.

Last thing to note is `sepBy` returns a list - so in the case where the parsing fails we still get an empty list as a result, if you want to see the failing use `sepBy1` instead!